# prevent to refresh a web page

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, webview

I have a problem : I have a simple application with a menu and a link that goes to the web page. The web page is: "soundcloud" it is a site that generates music. for example, if I put on a play music and I return to the menu of my application, the music is still running when I return to the web page, the music is still here but the page is returned to zero. and I want to prevent this. sorry for my english I'm french –

Cordialy
Davy

Comment: possible duplicate of [prevent to refresh a web page xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927564/prevent-to-refresh-a-web-page-xcode)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is assuming that the page is contained in a UIWebView within your app. If it's a link that opens in Safari, I don't believe you are going to be able to block navigation in Safari...but in your own web view you can.

Set the controlling class (whichever view controller contains your web view) as a UIWebView delegate. Then, when you implement the delegate protocol:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{      //If you want to block ANY navigation
    return NO;

       //If you want to block refreshes but allow other navigation
     if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeReload) return NO;
{
```

Comment: Also (again if this is your own UIWebView), make sure you aren't manually loading the page in your view controller if that's not the behavior you want...for example, in viewDidAppear, a call to load the page would load it each time that view appeared (not just when it initially loaded, as you probably want.)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!
I don't understand quite what I should do, I debuted in objective c
here's what I've already coded:   NSString *fullURL5 = @"<iframe    width=\"100%\" height=\"450\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"no\"    src=\"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?   url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fusers%2F1590077\"></iframe>";
       [[self soundcloud]loadHTMLString:fullURL5 baseURL:nil];

Comment: I'd need to see that code in context to understand what you're trying to do. Can you post the full code from the view controller that contains the web view?

Comment: yes of course !     - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL5 = @"<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"450\"     scrolling=\"no\"         frameborder=\"no\"     src=\"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?            url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fusers%2F1590077\"></iframe>";
    [[self soundcloud]loadHTMLString:fullURL5 baseURL:nil];
    }

Comment: OK, making a little more sense now...I get that you're calling something from the soundcloud API but unfortunately I'm not at all familiar with it. Are you just trying to play some music, or is it actually loading a web view? i.e., in your nib or storyboard, is there a UIWebView??

Comment: Can you post the whole file as code so we get the whole picture? Indent four spaces and it will format as code...

Comment: In fact, it works like a website, it is a widget.
as I told you earlier, when I activate music and I share then I'll be back in the webview, I just want the page does not load and I always see the play button to activate the music I started before. here is my project file : http://www14.zippyshare.com/v/2071723/file.html

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Reid Belton's answer

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{     
    //to prevent reloading html if it is already loaded
   if( isHTMLLoaded)
   {
       return NO;
   }else{
     isHTMLLoaded = YES;
    return YES;
   }

}
```